# Eclipse with ADT performance issue

Tags: android, eclipse, git, adt

I've been using ADT for about a year now. 
We have a Git project on bitbucket.

Just before Christmas I started having some performance issues when pulling/fetching from our repository. 
What appears to happen is that the fetch downloads the changes, but then my PC runs for hours resolving the deltas.
Looking at the task manager shows javaw.exe using a single core, and nearly a Gig of memory. It will eventually complete, but this process used to only take minutes. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Task Manager]

This is where it's "stuck"
[image: Operation Progress]

As you can see, it's not the worlds largest update.

- My Eclipse version is  4.2.1.v20130118-173121-9MF7GHYdG0B5kx4E_SkfZV-1mNjVATf67ZAb7.
- My ADT version is 23.0.2.1259578.
- JDK is now 1.7u75, it was 1.7u55 before I updated it.

I know this is a pretty random question, but I have no idea what else to try.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should try [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems more a stability problem of your pc. However if your problem seems to be on `javaw.exe` i suggest to update to last JDK jdk-8u31 you can find it for all platform on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html.

If is not a problem for your project try to change version of Eclipse switching to

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600

This is the last Eclipse version, code name Luna and supports well JDK 8.

Comment: This is actually an issue on both my desktop and laptop, so it can't be a problem with my PC. I'll have a go on a 3rd PC.

Comment: No other ideas for now except JDK and Eclipse config, but I will think about it.